# How to recursively calculate the average of digits

Tags: java, recursion

I need to calculate the average of digits.

For example:
n = 123,
average = (1+2+3)/3=2

So far I have managed to correctly calculate the sum, but I am having problems with getting the number of the digits in order to calculate the average. I would use 2 recursion methods to calculate the sum and number of digits, but I am only allowed to use 1 recursion method. I am also not allowed to use any global variables

```
public static int avg(int n, int sum, int i) {
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    sum =  n%10+avg(n/10, sum, i);
    i++;
    return sum/i;
}
```

Comment: Could you use an `int` array? That way just loop through the array, adding to the total, then divide by `array.size`?

Comment: For this specific problem, we are not allowed to use an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for multiple recursive methods.  You need to pass the sum and count of digits through the recursive method itself.  Because you can only return one variable, it's simplest to have the base case return the average.

Also, calculate the average as a `double` to avoid integer division truncating your answer.

```
public static double avg(int n, int sum, int i) {
    if(n==0)
        return (double) sum / i;
    return avg(n / 10, sum + n % 10, i + 1);
}
```

The base case returns the sum divided by the count that has accumulated so far.  Else, for the number `n`, pass `n / 10` to take off the ones digit.  For `sum`, add the last digit to the sum.  For `i`, increment the count.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work.

```
public static double avg(int n, int sum, int i) {
    if(n==0)
        return (double) sum/i;
    return avg(n/10,sum + n%10,i+1);
}
```

Calling with `avg(123,0,0)`.
With each recursion you increase the sum by the digit and increase `i` by 1 as the counter for the number of digits.

Comment: For an input of 1234, the correct answer should be 2.5.  Your solution says 2.

Comment: @pjs since it returns an `int` that is the case. One would have to change it into `double` as the accepted answer shows. I wasn't sure whether the op needed it.

Answer (score 0):

I like to write a front-end method for cases like this, to help end-users avoid the need to remember to use magical mystery values for the additional parameters needed by the recursion:

```
private static double avg(int n, int sum, int count) {
    if(n == 0)
        return (double) sum / count;
    return avg(n / 10, sum + n % 10, count + 1);
}

public static double avg(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0.0;
    return avg(n, 0, 0);
}
```

This allows you to set up default values for the recursive calculation without exposing them to the public.  This version also guards against the input being 0.